# Using http request headers to enforce caching of response

Tags: javascript, caching, http-headers, fetch

I'm working with a public API that is poorly configured, i.e. the server doesn't set the Cache-Control header when it should.

Can I use HTTP request headers or alter response headers, so that a response is cached at the browser level for some period of time?

In the context of this API the response will be fresh until a specific data time calculated previously.

I looked quite a bit, but cannot seem to find anything related to setting request headers.

Note, I'm working in javascript and using `fetch()` to make requests.

Here is the state of the current headers:

```
Request Headers
:authority: fantasy.premierleague.com
:method: GET
:path: /api/entry/1157414/event/3/picks/
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
```

```
Response Headers
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 571
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 25 Dec 2020 16:57:32 GMT
server: nginx/1.18.0
via: 1.1 google, 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
x-cache: MISS, MISS
x-cache-hits: 0, 0
x-served-by: cache-lhr7366-LHR, cache-fra19130-FRA
x-timer: S1608915452.118518,VS0,VE22
```

Comment: Response header cannot be updated at client side, as far as I know

Comment: You could use localStorage to create your own cache. Store date and data in separate keys and check there before making new request

Comment: @charlietfl yes thanks that what I'm trying next. Although it would be a lot cleaner if the results could be just cached at the browser level.